# Wordpress get_the_date() only retrieves post ID

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a loop of posts in my wp homepage where 5 recent posts are shown one below the other.
The code to loop wp data is

```
$args = array('numberposts'=>'5');
$recentposts = wp_get_recent_posts($args);  
foreach($recentposts as $post){
    $v = $post['ID'];
    echo 'Title:'.get_the_title($v).'<br>';
    echo 'Date:' .get_the_date($v).'<br>';
}
```

The Title section works perfectly, but Date section only shows the ID of the post and nothing else.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Always try to check function reference to see what parameter it takes:-https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_date/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look at the documentation : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_date

First parameters is format, second is ID, so :

```
// whatever your format
get_the_date('Y-m-d', $v)
```

To get your default Wordpress site date format :

```
$date_format = get_option( 'date_format' );
get_the_date( $date_format, $post_id );
```

Answer (score -2):

```
while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
    <li class="icon-date"><?php echo get_the_date( 'Y-m-d' ); ?></li>
    <li class="icon-time"><?php the_time( 'H:i:s' ); ?></li>
```

Comment: You should include something about WHY this is the right answer.